# Three.js - TypeError: THREE.Scene is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am just trying out Three.js so I can implement it to a project of mine, however when I run the first example in the documentation:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.js"></script>        
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: THREE.Scene is not a constructor

I tried adding scene.js, but it threw another error inside scene.js so it didn't work. I am using version r80 and I heard there was some non-working samples in the documentation, however I am not sure what's wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the `three.js` library is correct ? What happens if you try to go to it ? Try to track an eventual 404 in the errors

Comment: Yes the path is correct, the whole thing is in a directory in my computer.

Comment: can you double-check that this is actually this file you are loading as `three.js`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/build/three.js (i.e. the one from the `./build`-folder).

Comment: That worked. I was using the one in the src folder. Build one works now. Thank you. Can you add this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I came across this error when working with three and nextjs. I can't leave an answer, but it was resolved by switching ```import THREE from 'three'``` to ```import * as THREE from 'three'```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, the problem is the wrong `three.js`-file being included in the page. You should always use the file from the `./build`-folder of the three.js repository, or a version hosted by cdnjs: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js/

Answer (score 15):

I hit this snag because I was calling `new THREE.scene` instead of `new THREE.Scene` (capital S!)

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue but with

> THREE.MeshLambertMaterial

and the issue did appear because I wrote incorrectly

> THREE.MeshLamberMaterial without the letter 't'

maybe it can be of help for someone :)