# Using THREE.js TransformControls

Tags: javascript, three.js, jsbin

I am trying to use the THREE TransformControls class in a JSBin project that I am creating. Unfortunately, I cannot share my entire code. However, my JS code is within `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` HTML tags. All my imports are handled by `<script src=""> </script>` HTML tags. I have tried various source URLs for the TransformControls class to no avail.

I have imported the module using:  `<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js"></script>` but I keep getting a "Script error. (line 0)" as soon as I create a new TransformControls object.

Here is my TransformControls code:

```
var tC= new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement); // this line causes the error
var cC = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); // camera controls works
tC.addEventListener( 'mousemove', render );
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Disclaimer: I am **very** new to JavaScript and to THREE*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add crossorigin in your script tag

Code(Will work in jsbin):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r121/three.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> //<----here

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js" crossorigin></script> //<----here

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <script>
    //import {TransformControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js";
    var tC= new THREE.TransformControls(); //<-- not a complete code just for understanding
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Other helpful articles:

- https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/223
- [Cryptic "Script Error." reported in Javascript in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913978/cryptic-script-error-reported-in-javascript-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Just for knowledge:

> runner-4.1.8.min.js:1 THREE.TransformControls: As part of the transition to ES6 Modules, the files in 'examples/js' were deprecated in May 2020 (r117) and will be deleted in December 2020 (r124). You can find more information about developing using ES6 Modules in https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation.

Use

```
https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js
```

Comment: Hey @EP the solution I suggested is only for  "Script error. (line 0)" error, Your other errors are not related. This seems to be a versioning mismatch. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158103/starsgeometry0-setattribute-is-not-a-function and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099720/three-js-typeerror-three-scene-is-not-a-constructor

Comment: Thanks, @Dolly - I'll try this again if I have time